# Is it possible to make variables global from inside a function in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, scope

I'm trying to make a function that returns the id number of a certain user, but I can't access a variable that I declared in the function when I'm calling the function.

```
function loadlink($users){

    global $database, $rowz, $results;
    $results = $database->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$users}'");
    $rowz = $results->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    var_dump( $rowz); //returns basic array info
}

var_dump( $rowz); //returns "NULL"
loadlink('RandomUser');
```

var_dump( $rowz); returns the array info if I call loadlink() first, but the thing is that I want to use the $rowz variable when calling loadlink() to access a property of the returned associative array, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: your example doesn't reflect your request. Nowhere in loadlink() are you trying to access $rowz so there's no point in making it accessible. You could just have loadlink() return $rowz, but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking for

Comment: The goal is to call loadlink and pass in $rowz, like this: loadlink($rowz['username']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really return from your function what you need it to return and not use global variables for that.

But yes, it is possible using the `$GLOBALS` array although you would need to call your function first before you can access the variables you set in it:

```
function loadlink($users){
    global $database;

    $GLOBALS['results'] = $database->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$users}'");
    $GLOBALS['rowz'] = $results->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

// run function first to initialize the necessary variables
loadlink('RandomUser');
var_dump($rowz); //returns basic array info
```

Comment: I'm still getting NULL for some reason

`loadlink('RandomUser');
var_dump($GLOBALS['rowz']['username']);`
I don't think that would work with what I'm trying to do though. I want the loadlink() function to return the id of the username that is passed as a parameter. Maybe I would need 2 functions for this?
And how should I do this if using global variables isn't good? 
just using `return` on $rowz could potentially work in some way I guess but I'm not sure how to split loadlink() into 2 functions with  with the queries and the $users parameter

Comment: @MangoGarden You pass to the function what it needs and you have it return what you want back. About your `NULL` value, you are using `fetch_all()` so you get a multi-dimensional array so you would need `var_dump($GLOBALS['rowz'][0]['username']);`

Comment: Oh I see. If using the globals array is bad practice though, how should I split this function into 2 so I can use `return`?

Comment: Or should I ask a new question for that

Comment: @MangoGarden I think so, it's not really clear what you want to do just by the comments :-)